# How to keep pandas loc from transposing a single item dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

When I perform loc on a single element DataFrame object, it is getting transposed and converted to a float64 type.  Here is the example code to reproduce:

```
from pandas import read_excel, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rowNames = ['Name0', 'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']

df = DataFrame(
    [[3, 1366.436, 9.0],
    [3, 179.090, 14.0],
    [1, 322.297, 9.0],
    [1, 1604.821, 31.0],
    [8, 346.920, 20.0],
    [1, 2408.365, 31.0],
    [1, 765.352, 9.0],
    [1, 2295.521, 26.0],
    [8, 636.895, 20.0]],
    index=['Name0','Name0','Name1','Name1','Name1','Name2','Name3','Name3','Name3'],
    columns=['Layer', 'Length', 'Width']
    )

for i in range(len(rowNames)):
    print("Name = " +  str(rowNames[i]))
    nDF = df.loc[rowNames[i]]
    print(str(nDF) + "\n")
```

Notice what is happening to index "Name2" because it has only 1 item:

```
Name = Name0   
        Layer    Length  Width     
Name0      3  1366.436    9.0   
Name0      3   179.090   14.0   

Name = Name1   
        Layer    Length  Width     
Name1      1   322.297    9.0    
Name1      1  1604.821   31.0   
Name1      8   346.920   20.0   

Name = Name2    
Layer        1.000   
Length    2408.365   
Width       31.000   
Name: Name2, dtype: float64   

Name = Name3   
        Layer    Length  Width     
Name3      1   765.352    9.0   
Name3      1  2295.521   26.0   
Name3      8   636.895   20.0
```

This causes a mess downstream later in the code.
Maybe this conversion behavior is expected - but is there a way to override it?
Edited to fix formatting...  hope it looks better now (columns lined up a bit).

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a list into `loc` which guarantees to return a dataframe:

```
for i in range(len(rowNames)):
    print("Name = " +  str(rowNames[i]))
    nDF = df.loc[rowNames[i:i+1]]  # difference here
    print(str(nDF) + "\n")
```

Output:

```
Name = Name0
       Layer    Length  Width
Name0      3  1366.436    9.0
Name0      3   179.090   14.0

Name = Name1
       Layer    Length  Width
Name1      1   322.297    9.0
Name1      1  1604.821   31.0
Name1      8   346.920   20.0

Name = Name2
       Layer    Length  Width
Name2      1  2408.365   31.0

Name = Name3
       Layer    Length  Width
Name3      1   765.352    9.0
Name3      1  2295.521   26.0
Name3      8   636.895   20.0
```

Comment: Amazing!  Stupendous!  Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I like this one:

```
nDF = df.loc[df.index == rowNames[i], :]
```

But in general I would prefer to put the Name* in one extra column instead of having an index with duplicated values.